# How can I get my CSS media queries to work?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I can't get my CSS media queries to work. I've worked with them in the past and they worked for me, but on this particular site, they don't function. I added `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` but it still doesn't work. [this is my HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeY5W.png) and this is my only CSS media query `@media and screen ( max-width: 700px ) {.header-image {display: none;}}` Do you see a mistake somewhere? I'm pretty sure it will be something totally minor, but I spent hours trying to make it work and haven't been successful so far. Thanks a lot:)

Comment: Hi. Please paste the html and css + media queries here, or make a sandbox.

Comment: Please don't post images of code and see how to create [mre]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax of your code is wrong

This is the valid media query

```
@media screen and ( max-width: 700px ) { ... }
```

Comment: Tip: Use a linter ;)